# PHP Include funtion not working

Tags: php, html, include

So I created a header.php file to store the basic html markup, but when I try to include it in my php code it just doesn't work. The output is as is like my code on my text editor.

```
<?php
include ("header.php");
?>

            <section class="main-container">
                <div class="main-wrapper">
                    <h2>HOME</h2>
                </div>
            </section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `?php` need to be `<?php`. check the syntax. Seems just a TYPO mistake only. if still not worked after change that means `header.php` file is not in same working location(directory),it's in some other folder which you are trying to include directly. so check and provide proper path then

Comment: If it isn't the typo issue perhaps the file isn't PHP, you aren't running it through a server, or PHP isn't installed. If you ever see `<?php` in the source you have an issue with the way the file is being served.

Comment: is your page showing something like `?php.....` ?

Comment: Seems OP is MIA

Comment: I assume that you are a developer. Saying that it doesn't work is not helpful at all. Ever heard of debugging?

Comment: Hi all i really appreciate your answers and to be honest ive tried all those stuff that you mentioned before come here im not a genius developer and im just triying to learn my way back to programming as well. the header file is in the main directory along with my index.php file . there is no TYPO as well

Comment: hi akintunde no im not a developer at all and im just starting to code. and yes ive heard about debugging as well. im saying that it doesnt work really because it just doesnt work on my end.

Comment: So is the problem that the file doesn't get included or you have problems with the `header.php` file?

Comment: the webpage that im building is working fine, now i wanted to include a log in system with it so decided to try and code PHP. so to make it neat of course we used include header php working ok. syntax is also good not being detected by my text editor if there is something wrong ive placed the header.php file to a folder and remove it and placed it on the root directory just to be sure but still no go

Comment: Try another file with something like this as the contents: `<?php echo 'hello earth';`  Does that get interpreted correctly?

Comment: your running this on a php enabled web server?

Comment: Hi @Progrock ive tried what you said same result above ive created a new file named it test.php placed the php code in it saved it on the root directory with index.php same output as above it just outputs my code on the browser

Comment: @mNm, again edit your question to reflect what you have tried.  Be verbose.  Explain what you've tried, giving example code and describe what happened, and what you expected.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Answer (score 1):

1. Try this syntax and pay attention to the opening tag:

   `<?php
        include ("header.php");
   ?>`
2. Make sure that file *header.php* is in the same directory as this file that you are coding and this file has an extension of .php
3. Make sure that `include` is not disabled from `php.ini` (unlikely, unless someone deliberately did it)

Comment: HI thank you for answering Ive already tried all those but still the same issue dont know what else to do

Comment: @mNm Please Turn on error reporting, and tell what it says.

Comment: @mNm, if you've tried something, edit your original post to reflect that. :)

Comment: @Progrock hi thank you for that im still new to this website and i appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure all files have .php extension

  ```
  include('header.php');
  ```
- Use include function script in the top of your php file
- Filename must not be space

Comment: hi thank you for answering . all my files have PHP ext. 
include scipt on top of my php file
filename also not spaced 
still no go

Comment: please see your page source of index.php file

Comment: @ParthoKar filenames can have spaces, and works fine with an include statement for me.

Comment: @ParthoKar, what do you mean by top of your php file?  I use 'include's all over the shop.

Comment: @ParthoKar while it's common for files that contain code to have a `php` file extension, it's not necessarily a prerequisite.

Answer (score 1):

Check php opening tag. it should be `<?php` not like this  `?php`

```
<?php
 include ("header.php");
?>
```